# Sync Palm Centro pictures on Linux

Tags: synchronization, images, linux

I have a Palm Centro, and I'd like to copy the pictures to my computer. However, I'm using Ubuntu, and I don't want to switch to Windows or use Palm's horrible sync application (through Wine.) Is there a Linux application I can use to easily copy my pictures from my phone to my computer? I'd prefer a simple command-line script to a monolithic productivity suite.

Answer (score 2):

Have you attempted to use the "Palm OS devices" menu option in System -> Preferences? (It may be in System -> Administration, I'm not in front of my Ubuntu boxes.)

(Full disclosure: This answer assumes that a/your Palm Centro doesn't run Windows Mobile.)

Answer (score 1):

Download [J-pilot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-Pilot). once installed, I googled "pictures and video plugin j-pilot." Install it, restart, re-sync. All of your pictures and videos will now be on your computer. Magic.